# How can I add an extra option in the dropdown generated by form?

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

I've a form builder like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('file','file')
        ->add('concurs','entity', array('class' => 'MCFrontEndBundle:Concurs'))
    ;
}
```

As you can see, it shows a input to select a file, and then a dropdown to select any option that is filled by Concurs entity.

Can I add manually an option like "None"?

Comment: Chill. Maybe you just didn't understand my question. Will remove the tag PHP as just symfony2 programmers should come to try to read this. Extrangers won't understand :D. My bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The entity form type, or to be particular all choice types, has an option called [empty_value](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#empty-value), which is exactly what you need.

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('file','file')
        ->add('concurs','entity', array(
            'class' => 'MCFrontEndBundle:Concurs',
            'empty_value' => 'None',
            'required' => false
        ))
    ;
}
```